# How do I install .tar.gz, .tar.bz2, and .tar.bz files?

Tags: launcher, package-management, install-from-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a .tar.gz  (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Help! I found a program that I really, really want, but they only have a .tar.gz file for the download, and it just opens the archive manager after I download it. What do I do?